# What's happening with the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq-updates

The voting question has been locked, but there's no indication of what the status is.  For those of us who haven't been on The Comms Room lately (where I assume it's been discussed), would it be possible for someone to add a note indicating what's happening with it?  (e.g. approved and waiting for it to be made active, didn't get approved, being discussed by SF and SE mods, whatever...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've sent a message off to the Developers, since changing the faq requires (as I understand it) a site version iteration since it's part of the static files of serverfault.com. We're waiting on word right now.

Comment: Did the removal of "no exceptions" make it in?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Since the edit round was done, I was not monitoring the edit question. So no, it didn't make the final copy. However, I see a lot of interest in striking that language. Of all the suggested edits after the edit round closed, all but that one are minor or cosmetic. By the rules we should have a normal edit question after the FAQ goes live, but it already has enough votes to 'pass'. So I'm going to short-circuit that and make the edit.